# How to auth in spotipy without open web browser?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I tried the standard methods (which are described on the home page), but I need to log in without a web browser. How can I do this?

Comment: not sure I understood your question right, but you might want to take a look at what they did in spotifyd (open source spotify client daemon)

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of Spotify's python libraries, for example: https://github.com/plamere/spotipy

In the repo you can see an example with user authentication

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id="YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID",
                                               client_secret="YOUR_APP_CLIENT_SECRET",
                                               redirect_uri="YOUR_APP_REDIRECT_URI",
                                               scope="user-library-read"))

results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
for idx, item in enumerate(results['items']):
    track = item['track']
    print(idx, track['artists'][0]['name'], " – ", track['name'])
```

(need to install the library first: `pip install spotipy`)

Another python library https://tekore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/:

```
import tekore as tk

conf = (client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
token = tk.prompt_for_user_token(*conf, scope=tk.scope.every)

spotify = tk.Spotify(token)
tracks = spotify.current_user_top_tracks(limit=10)
spotify.playback_start_tracks([t.id for t in tracks.items])
```

Comment: According to the title OP uses spotipy... This means that your answer is fine, just the first sentence is not necessary...

Comment: I also use this library. The problem is that the first time you start the program, it opens a web browser to log in. And I just need to log in without opening a web browser